# Python imports being overridden by the standard library (Python 2.4)

Tags: python, python-2.4

I have a python package that I'm writing and I'm having an issue where the standard library is being imported instead of my files because of name clashes.

For example, a file structure like below:

#### `package/__init__.py`

```
# No data in this file
```

#### package/module.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Loading module.py'
import signal
```

#### package/signal.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Loading signal.py'
```

I get the following results when I run this:

```
$ ./module.py
Loading module.py
```

I would like to get:

```
$ ./module.py
Loading module.py
Loading signal.py
```

## The actual question:

So, when I run **module.py**, it's `import signal` goes to the stdlib version. How am I able to force **module.py** to import signal.py instead?

As noted in the tags, this needs to be able to run on python-2.4.3. While that is an old version, it's what is included in RHEL 5.

---

#### Some additional information

Just for a bit more information, I explicitly have the following setup:

```
[10:30pm][~/test] tree .
.
|-- package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module.py
|   `-- signal.py
`-- script

[10:30pm][~/test] cat script
#!/usr/bin/env python
from package import signal

[10:30pm][~/test] cat package/__init__.py

[10:30pm][~/test] cat package/module.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Loading module.py"
import signal

[10:30pm][~/test] cat package/signal.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Loading signal.py"

[10:30pm][~/test] python ./script
Loading signal.py

[10:32pm][~/test] python ./package/module.py 
Loading module.py

[10:32pm][~/test] python -m package.module
python: module package.module not found
```

Please note that when I ran **./package/module.py** that the print statement in **./package/signal.py** was not fired. This implies that the signal that was loaded is the one from the stdlib.

Comment: What's wrong with renaming your packages to avoid a name clash?

Comment: @S.Lott: While in this example it does conflict with something in the standard library, won't this also occur if the user installs an egg that clashes?

Comment: Don't use RHEL :). `./configure; make; make install`. Blau

Comment: There is nothing wrong with RHEL. Your suggestion should recommend make altinstall, since upgrading python will trash a RHEL 5 system, which requires 2.4 to be /usr/bin/python or yum will stop functioning. A better alternative is to get Python 2.6 from the EPEL. He doesn't need to upgrade python, so why should he change from a stable OS to do so?

Comment: But I get the following: `$ python2 -m package.module` => 
`Loading module.py
Loading signal.py`

Comment: @FelixYan: Are you running python 2.4?

Comment: @Felix Yan: `-m` works properly only on Python2.6+ http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-366-explicit-relative-imports-from-a-main-module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in this case is that the built-in `signal` module is imported as part of the interpreter's startup process. So by the time your code in `module.py` runs, there is *already* an entry in `sys.modules` under the name `signal`, with the built-in module as its value. Since `sys.modules` is the first place the `import` statement looks, it's going to return that built-in module and stop there. It doesn't even bother to look for your own custom `signal.py`.

I can think of three solutions:

1. Rename your module. This is the easiest solution. You don't have to worry about your module names clashing with installed packages (eggs), because *normally* the `import` statement will search directories in the order specified by `sys.path`, and the current working directory when you run the interpreter is first on that list. `signal` is sort of a special case because it gets imported automatically before your code runs, but there are a limited number of modules for which that is true, and those are the only ones you have to avoid name clashes with.
2. You can `del sys.modules['signal']` and replace the entry with your own custom `signal` module. **Don't actually do this** unless your module is truly meant to be a drop-in replacement for the built-in `signal`. If you do, then any code that runs `import signal` from that point on will get *your* version, not the built-in one, and that could wreak havoc on any internal code that needs the `signal` module to function.
3. You can use the [`imp` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module-imp.html) to get access to the internals of the `import` function, or at least equivalent code, which will allow you to bypass the check of `sys.modules`.

   If you really do need to do this, here's a code sample you could use:

   ```
   import imp, sys

   f, path, desc = imp.find_module('signal', sys.path)
   if f:
       f.close()
       signal = imp.new_module('signal')
       execfile(path, signal.__dict__)
   else:
       raise ImportError('signal.py not found')
   # signal is your module
   ```

   This code snippet is roughly equivalent to `import signal` except that it does not insert  the module found into `sys.modules`, and it does not look for builtin modules before searching the path.

Comment: That's really quite lame. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From the project directory (a parent of `package` directory):

```
python -mpackage.state # Python 2.6+
python2.4 -c'from package.state import test; test()'
```

- always use absolute imports in your modules i.e., `import package.signal` instead of `import signal` unless you know what you're doing
- make sure that `package`'s parent directory is in `sys.path`. `unittest2`, `nose`, `pytest` test runners might do it for you
- avoid module names that conflict with stdlib modules. Many test runners, code analyzers are broken and add directories with a module being processed to `sys.path`
- `python package/stat.py` adds `package` to `sys.path` (see http://bugs.python.org/issue13475). You don't want that in this case

Answer (score -1):

**File Hierarchy**

```
.
|-- package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module.py
|   `-- signal.py
`-- script
`-- __init__.py
```

**script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from package import module
```

**package/module.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Loading module.py'
from package import signal
```

**package/signal.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Loading signal.py'
```

Output:

```
$ ./script 
Loading module.py
Loading signal.py
```

**Edit**

Just tested this with a modification to the module.py, on python 2.4.3

Comment: @sharth - Sorry. Just made a change and tested it on python 2.4.3

Comment: I've updated the gist with new output. I agree that ./script will run. That has always been the case. I'd also like to be able to execute ./package/signal.py.